# Seg Fault occurs while malloc-ing

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault, malloc

This function is a part of program which will gain statistics about books (amount of specific letters, words etc.). Thing is that segmentation fault appears when trying to malloc:

`*wordArray[arrayIndex] = malloc(sizeof(***wordArray)*(wcslen(newWord)+1));`

after reallocing whole array

`*wordArray = realloc(*wordArray, (arrayIndex+1)*sizeof(**wordArray));`

I know that realloc isn't really efficent but the most important thing at the moment is to understand why it doesn't work at all. Thanks a lot.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wctype.h>
#include <wchar.h>

#define X 2

void wordManager(wchar_t ***, int **, wchar_t *);
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    wchar_t **wordArray;
    int *wordAmount;
    wchar_t word[50];

    for(int i=0; i<X; i++){
        scanf("%ls", word);
        wordManager(&wordArray, &wordAmount, word);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<X; i++){
        printf("%ls; %d times\n", wordArray[i], wordAmount[i]);
    }
}

void wordManager(wchar_t ***wordArray, int **wordAmount, wchar_t *newWord){
    static int isArrayInitialised = 0;
    static int isArrayEmpty = 1;
    static int arrayIndex = 0;
    int wordLocation;

    if(!isArrayInitialised){
        *wordArray = malloc(sizeof(**wordArray)*1);
        if(*wordArray==NULL){
            printf("Error mallocing wordArray");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        *wordAmount = calloc(1, sizeof(*wordAmount));
        if(*wordAmount==NULL){
            printf("Error callocing wordAmount");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        isArrayInitialised = 1;
    }
    if(isArrayEmpty){
        *wordArray[0] = malloc(sizeof(***wordArray)*(wcslen(newWord)+1));
        wcscpy(*wordArray[0], newWord);
        *wordAmount[0] = 1;
        isArrayEmpty = 0;
    }
    else{
        //Check if word is already in an array.
        wordLocation = 0;
        for(; wordLocation<arrayIndex+1; wordLocation++){
            if(!wcscmp(*wordArray[wordLocation], newWord))  break;
        }
        printf("%d\n", wordLocation);
        //Word hasn't been found. Then:
        if(wordLocation==arrayIndex+1){
            arrayIndex++; //Increase arrays' volume.
            *wordArray = realloc(*wordArray, (arrayIndex+1)*sizeof(**wordArray));
            if(*wordArray==NULL){
                printf("Error reallocating wordArray memory.\n Array index: %d", arrayIndex);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            *wordAmount = realloc(*wordAmount, (arrayIndex+1)*sizeof(**wordAmount));
            if(*wordAmount==NULL){
                printf("Error reallocating wordAmount memory.\n Array index: %d", arrayIndex);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            *wordArray[arrayIndex] = malloc(sizeof(***wordArray)*(wcslen(newWord)+1));
            wcscpy(*wordArray[arrayIndex], newWord);
            *wordAmount[arrayIndex] = 1;
        }
        //Word has been found in an array.
        else{
            (*wordAmount[wordLocation])++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Postfix `[]` has higher precedence than unary `*`. But a three-star programmer should already know that.

Comment: I know that [] can be used here instead of *. Furthermore pointer asterix has got really low priority. Is it the case of wrong syntax in terms of precedence here?

Comment: Apparently I need to be *quite* explicit here: What do you believe `*x[y] = z;` does, particularly considering my previous comment?

Comment: Oh.. ok.. I see. So instead of getting (*x)[y] = *(*x+y) I get *x[y] = **(x+y) = a[x][]. I can write a[][x] as well to get *(*x+y), right?

Comment: If by `a[][x]` you mean `a[0][x]`, then yes.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you very much.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  Suggest enabling all warnings when compiling, then fixing those warnings.  1) the parameters to `main()` are not used, so the signature should be: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding this line: `scanf("%ls", word);` 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) the input format specifier: `'%ls` is nonsense.  3) when using the '%s' format specifier, always use a 'max characters' modifier, that is one less than the length of the input buffer to avoid buffer overflow, undefined behaviour and a seg fault event.  Suggest: `if( 1 != scanf( "%49s", word) ) { /* handle scanf error */ }`

Comment: it would be much better to use the function: `wprintf()` for wide character printing rather than using `printf()`

Comment: @user3629249 I just wanted to sum up the problem, so I quickly wrote a piece of code just to show it. You're right of course. Thanks for all tips and suggestions. I'm a newbie coder :)